# How to mock a constructor for jasmine that is checked with instanceof

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

This is the first time I am asking a question, in case I am missing any vital information let me know. Unit testing and Mocking is still quite confusing to me, so I hope some kind soul might be able to clear things up.

I am unit testing an angular service (even though I believe that it should make no difference if I was using plain Javascript only). As part of this I want to test a method which takes as parameter an instance of a customClass:

```
unit.method(new customClass());
```

Inside the actual 'method' I check if the parameter is instanceof customClass (which I inject and is of itself also an angular service);

```
service.prototype.method = function(param) {
   if (param instanceof customClass) {
      throw new Error 'Parameter has to be of customClass'
    }
```

1. Question: 
   From my understanding of unit testing - I would have to mock the customClass constructor. Correct?
2. Question: How do I achieve that? Can you mock a constructor so that instanceof customClass still returns true?